# Returning an order object in a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops

So I am confused as to how to operate this function `allCandyOrders`. My code is as thus

```
let inventory = [
  { candy: "Twizzlers", inStock: 180, weeklyAverage: 200 },
  { candy: "Sour Patch Kids", inStock: 90, weeklyAverage: 100 },
  { candy: "Milk Duds", inStock: 300, weeklyAverage: 170 },
  { candy: "Now and Laters", inStock: 150, weeklyAverage: 40 }
];

function allCandyOrders (inventory){
  let candyOrder = {}
  for (let i=0; i<inventory.length; i++){
      if (inventory[i].inStock > inventory[i].weeklyAverage){
         candyOrder.push(0)
      }
      if (inventory[i].inStock < inventory[i].weeklyAverage){
        candyOrder.push(inventory[i].candy + inventory[i].weeklyAverage*2)
      }
    }
  return candyOrder
}
```

What I am being tested on shows that I fail to 'return an object with the right values for the inventory array.' Also that I fail to 'return an object with the right values for an alternative inventory.' With this being the error code

```
ReferenceError: candy is not defined
    at allCandyOrders (test.js:12:32)
    at Context.it (test.js:66:12)
```

I am trying to have the code return

````
  "Twizzlers": 400,
  "Sour Patch Kids": 200,
  "Milk Duds": 0,
  "Now and Laters": 0
}```
````

Comment: One problem is that candyOrder.push(0) doesn't make sense, as push is only defined on arrays and candyOrder is not an array.

Comment: Could you clarify what the function is supposed to do?

Comment: `if (inventory[i].candy === candy)` what is the example value of the left `candy`

Comment: either you need to define `candy` value outside the function or pass a candy value as 2nd `parameter` in function so that it can filter the data based on that candy parameter.

Comment: another error you will encounter is *candyOrder.push is not a function* so you need to make sure `candyOrder` is an array to use push method on it.

Comment: so how do I recall the candy that needs ordering and the order number without pushing?

Answer (score 0):

$

```
    function candyOrderQuantity(inventory, candy) {
    //function to cycle inventory
      let order = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < inventory.length; i++) {
    
    //cycle inventory for instock quantity less then weekly 
    //average and candy name matchs inventory  
      if (inventory[i].weeklyAverage >= inventory[i].inStock 
      && inventory[i].candy === candy) {
    //if the results match then multiple the weeklyAverage by 
    //2 and return order
      order = inventory[i].weeklyAverage * 2;
    return order;
   }

   if (inventory[i].weeklyAverage < inventory[i].inStock) {
    return 0;
   }


   }
   }
```

$

Comment: it would be helpful to write some comments explaining why this code answers the OP's question and why their code was deficient.